# How to use sed to get all link to other file

Tags: regex, shell, sed, command

I have a file with detail like this

```
    <hasURL rdf:datatype="&xsd;string"><![CDATA[http://media.foody.vn/res/g4/36211/s/foody-dragon-beach-bar-635453535582622303.JPG ]]></hasURL>
    <hasURL rdf:datatype="&xsd;string"><![CDATA[http://media.foody.vn/res/g4/36211/s/foody-dragon-beach-bar-635453535573574287.JPG ]]></hasURL>
    <hasURL rdf:datatype="&xsd;string"><![CDATA[http://media.foody.vn/res/g4/36211/s/foody-dragon-beach-bar-635438897530827768.JPG ]]></hasURL>
    <hasURL rdf:datatype="&xsd;string"><![CDATA[192.168.1.1 ]]></hasURL>
    <hasURL rdf:datatype="&xsd;string"><![CDATA[192.168.1.1 ]]></hasURL>
```

I use this command

```
grep 'hasURL.*' inputfile.txt  | sed 's/^.*CDATA\\[\\([^>]\\+\\)]].*$/\\1/g' > output.txt
```

to get all link in `CDATA[]` to output.txt.
Now, i want get only link starting with `http`, not start with a number. How can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a sed search condition at the first.

```
grep 'hasURL.*' inputfile.txt | sed -n '/CDATA\[http:\/\//s~^.*CDATA\[\([^>]\+\)\]\].*$~\1~p'
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat yi
    <hasURL rdf:datatype="&xsd;string"><![CDATA[http://media.foody.vn/res/g4/36211/s/foody-dragon-beach-bar-635453535582622303.JPG ]]></hasURL>
    <hasURL rdf:datatype="&xsd;string"><![CDATA[http://media.foody.vn/res/g4/36211/s/foody-dragon-beach-bar-635453535573574287.JPG ]]></hasURL>
    <hasURL rdf:datatype="&xsd;string"><![CDATA[http://media.foody.vn/res/g4/36211/s/foody-dragon-beach-bar-635438897530827768.JPG ]]></hasURL>
    <hasURL rdf:datatype="&xsd;string"><![CDATA[192.168.1.1 ]]></hasURL>
    <hasURL rdf:datatype="&xsd;string"><![CDATA[192.168.1.1 ]]></hasURL>
$ sed -n '/CDATA\[http:\/\//s~^.*CDATA\[\([^>]\+\)\]\].*$~\1~p' yi
http://media.foody.vn/res/g4/36211/s/foody-dragon-beach-bar-635453535582622303.JPG 
http://media.foody.vn/res/g4/36211/s/foody-dragon-beach-bar-635453535573574287.JPG 
http://media.foody.vn/res/g4/36211/s/foody-dragon-beach-bar-635438897530827768.JPG
```

`/CDATA\[http:\/\//` regex pattern will search for the lines which contain `CDATA[http://` and do the replacement on those lines only ie, it replaces all the characters on those lines with the characters inside the group index 1.

**OR**

If your grep supports `-P`, then you could do this through grep itself.

```
grep -oP '^(?=.*hasURL).*CDATA\[\Khttp://\S+?(?=\s*]])' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
    <hasURL rdf:datatype="&xsd;string"><![CDATA[http://media.foody.vn/res/g4/36211/s/foody-dragon-beach-bar-635453535582622303.JPG ]]></hasURL>
    <hasURL rdf:datatype="&xsd;string"><![CDATA[http://media.foody.vn/res/g4/36211/s/foody-dragon-beach-bar-635453535573574287.JPG ]]></hasURL>
    <hasURL rdf:datatype="&xsd;string"><![CDATA[http://media.foody.vn/res/g4/36211/s/foody-dragon-beach-bar-635438897530827768.JPG ]]></hasURL>
    <hasURL rdf:datatype="&xsd;string"><![CDATA[192.168.1.1 ]]></hasURL>
    <hasURL rdf:datatype="&xsd;string"><![CDATA[192.168.1.1 ]]></hasURL>
foo
bar
$ grep -oP '^(?=.*hasURL).*CDATA\[\Khttp://\S+?(?=\s*]])' file
http://media.foody.vn/res/g4/36211/s/foody-dragon-beach-bar-635453535582622303.JPG
http://media.foody.vn/res/g4/36211/s/foody-dragon-beach-bar-635453535573574287.JPG
http://media.foody.vn/res/g4/36211/s/foody-dragon-beach-bar-635438897530827768.JPG
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/hasURL/s/.*CDATA\[\(http[^]]*\)\].*/\1/p' file
```

This turns on seds grep-like processing, restricts the lines to those containing `hasURL` and gets all details inside `CDATA[http...]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straightforward extension is to use

```
sed -n 's/^.*CDATA\[\([^>]\+\)]].*$/\1/g; /^http/ p'
```

That is, just adding `/^http/ p` to the sed script and calling sed with `-n`. Then it'll only print the result of the substitution if it matches `^http`.

EDIT: Your backslashes were duplicated, I removed the duplication. If there was a reason you had double backslashes there, just keep using your version of that part of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Try this awk version and get your result

```
awk -F[ '$3 ~ /^http/{sub("]+.*","",$3);print $3 }'
```